# Point styling in web-map in openlayers library

Tags: openlayers, point, style

I want to style points (vector data) in openlayers. So far console does not show any errors, but points are not displayed as well. My code:

```
let urlLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: urlSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
        }),
    })
})
```

Points disappearing after I am adding style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points can only be styled with `image` or `text` options.  An image can be a RegularShape or Circle, and that can have `fill`, for example

```
let urlLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: urlSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 5,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)'
            }),
        }),
    })
})
```